# Single word for something that attaches things together

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that represents a thing/entity whose sole purpose is to attach 2 things together. Apparently *attacher* isn't an English word. It needs to be generic and can apply to living or non-living things.

EDIT: As suggested a usage could be something that attaches computer processes together or living objects together. The word should not affect the integrity of the objects itself

Comment: look up words that mean "binder"

Comment: Can you provide an example, or examples, of such a "thing"? Would a tow-rope be one? Perhaps "connector" is your word.

Comment: @WS2 something that attaches computer processes together or living objects together, but does not affect the integrity of the objects itself.

Comment: Based off of  what I told WS2 @J.Taylor your suggestion can be seen as, taking an example of paper binding, making holes to bind things..

Comment: ...you need to rewrite your question to reflect what you need. .."binding" need not affect the integrity of the materials bound... "integrator"   may work

Comment: ...but you need to supply a context and show what you have already found

Comment: The sole purpose of a _link_ is to connect two other things together (as in a chain).

Comment: In DIY stores they're grouped under 'fixings'.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the word '**link**'.

> a. A connecting part, whether in material or immaterial sense; a thing (occasionally a person) serving to establish or maintain a connection; a member of a series or succession; a means of connexion or communication.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108729?rskey=CjTFoq&result=2#eid)

> a connecting structure
>
> something analogous to a link of chain
>
> a connecting element or factor

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link)